# Text parsing from mobile screen

Tags: python, ocr

i have extracted channels list information from youtube mobile screen after applying OCR on that. The extracted text is un-organized in terms of \n line break . So while parsing there is no certain rule for extracting each channel info . Due to unordered \n and \n\n i missed some channel info . Do you guys have idea of how can i do that so none of channel info missed .

Channel Name 1
description of channel 1

channel Name 2
description of channel 2

channel Name 3
(see here extra line break but in above case no extra line break between channel and description)
description of channel 3

Answer (score 0):

Using the Python list method `.replace("pattern", "replacement")` you can reorganize your line breaks. If you want to transform all the double line breaks into one line break, for example, you can do this:

```
text = text.replace("\n\n", "\n")
```

This will replace all the double line breaks with single line breaks.

If you want to go even further and remove all line breaks, having spaces instead, you can do this:

```
text = text.replace("\n", " ")
```

This will replace all your line breaks with spaces.

And parting from that, you can customize the method call to fit your needs.